# Why is RegionPlot@ImplicitRegion taking so long to compute?

Tags: plotting, regions

I have an equation as a function of $a$ and $\theta$ and would like to visualise the intersection between this graph and a flat plane at a height of 1 unit. I tried using the `RegionPlot@ImplicitRegion` method:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m[θ_] := √Abs[Sin[θ]]; 
F2[a_, θ_] := -15 m [θ] a Cot[m[θ] a]^3 + 
  15 Cot[m[θ] a ]^2 - 9 m [θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] + 
  4; (*-pi<theta<0*)
G2[a_, θ_] := -2 (m[θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] - 
    1);(*-pi<theta<0*)
U = 1
Q2[a_, θ_] := -(Cos[θ]/(9 m[θ]^4)) F2[
    a, θ] + U/m[θ]^2 G2[a, θ];(*-pi<theta<0*)

RegionPlot@
  ImplicitRegion[
   Q2[a, θ] == 
    1, {{a, 1, 8}, {θ, -π + 0.001, -0.001}}]
```

Why is Mathematica taking so long to plot the graph? Is it due to the complexity of the equation or other reasons? How should I modify the code? Thank you very much.

Comment: `RegionPlot@DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[...]`

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot[
 Q2[a, θ] == 1, {a, 1, 8}, {θ, -π + 0.001, -0.001}]
```

[image]

Since `RegionPlot` not always auto discretize the region, so we need to add
`DiscretizeRegion` by hand.

```
RegionPlot@
 DiscretizeRegion@
  ImplicitRegion[
   Q2[a, θ] == 
    1, {{a, 1, 8}, {θ, -π + 0.001, -0.001}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

m[θ_] := √Abs[Sin[θ]];
F2[a_, θ_] := -15 m[θ] a Cot[m[θ] a]^3 + 
   15 Cot[m[θ] a]^2 - 9 m[θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] + 4;
(*-pi<theta<0*)

G2[a_, θ_] := -2 (m[θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] - 
    1);(*-pi<theta<0*)
U = 1;
Q2[a_, θ_] := -(Cos[θ]/(9 m[θ]^4)) F2[a, θ] + 
   U/m[θ]^2 G2[a, θ];
(*-pi<theta<0*)
```

You appear to be confusing [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) and [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html). A region is the input to `Region`. The argument to `RegionPlot` is a predicate that must evaluate to `True` or `False`. In either case it is easier to evaluate when `Q2[a,θ] <= 1` rather than `Q2[a,θ] == 1`

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[
  Q2[a, θ] <= 1, {{a, 1, 8}, {θ, -π + 0.001, -0.001}}],
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[Q2[a, θ] <= 1 && 1 <= a <= 8 && -Pi < θ < 0,
 {a, 1, 8}, {θ, -π + 0.001, -0.001},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]